# How does one disable C/C++ support for a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Every now and again, I make the mistake of trying to enable C/C++ support in an Android Studio project. I think that I might like to use C/C++, but I forget that, at least on my system, I've never once been able to get it to work, even after downloading the NDK library.

I've looked around for how to remove C/C++ support from a project, but it seems the only things you can find are questions (and answers) on how to enable/disable NDK support, rather than how to remove the support from a project.

So, how does one do that?

Comment: Just don't include any C++?  It can't compile code that isn't there.

Comment: @GabeSechan It still tries to link to the library (libnative.so, I think) which causes the code to crash when I run it on the emulator. So something has to be manually turned off.

Comment: If the emulator is crashing, then your problem isn't c++ support. Most likely some library you use had native code, and doesn't have it compiled for the right abi. If you're using a x86-64 image try an x86 one

Comment: @GabeSechan No, the problem is that Gradle has some setting somewhere to enable C/C++ support. This was a new project, for which I had checked the "C/C++ Support" box. **To wit:** If I copy the Java, Kotlin, and layout files out, delete the project, re-create it without checking that box, then copy the Java, Kotlin, and layout files back in, the project works flawlessly on the emulator. I just did this today.

Comment: Then you're the first person in history with this problem. Or you're using the wrong version of the simulator, which happens all the time. I know which one I'm betting on.

Comment: Not to mention if that actually worked-why are you here, your problem is solved.

Comment: I'll grant I may well be the first person in history with this problem (though I've seen the same error elsewhere). How does one use the wrong version of the emulator, when it's the one supplied by Android Studio itself?

Comment: "if that actually worked-why are you here, your problem is solved." Because deleting a project, copying files out, creating a new project, and copying files back in is a huge hassle with the potential for error?

Comment: Android studio provides dozens of emulator images. Some are 32 bit, some are 64. Many libraries don't compile 64 bit binaries for x86, as there are no Android devices like that. Use that version, and almost every native library will explode in the simulator

Comment: But regardless enabling C++ but not using it causes no problems.  If you have a problem, its something else you did.

Comment: "But regardless enabling C++ but not using it causes no problems." Well, no, it caused problems from the get-go. AS didn't include CMake, so I got a gradle error. At first the error was useless (":app did not sync" or some such) but eventually I got it to where it said I had to download CMake. Then I had to download something else (I forget what). Even then it wouldn't compile a simple test program, so I removed the lines in `build.gradle` that enabled C/C++. At this point the thing compiled, but when I tried to run it on the emulator it complained that it couldn't find `libnative.so`.

Comment: I use C++ support, never downloaded CMake.  Once again-  its somehting else you're doing.

Comment: I literally had not one single C++ file in the code, and AS would not play ball. So then I tried to figure out how to un-enable C/C++ support and that brought me to the point where I posted this question.

Comment: "I use C++ support, never downloaded CMake." Well, if you're willing to give a constructive comment on how I might figure out the problem, I'd be grateful.

Comment: (And heck, if you can answer the question, I'd even vote you up and give you points!)

Comment: FWIW, I remembered what else I had to download: the NDK. I thought it odd Enabling C/C++ support did not automatically download the NDK.

Comment: @JohnPerry: Did you forget to remove the `static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }` block that AS adds to your java code when you enable C++ support (and any `native` java method declarations that were auto-added)?

Comment: Of the top of my head, I can suggest one weird scenario. If the path to Android SDK or the path to your project has spaces, then NDK support can easily go nuts. FWIW, I wouldn't entrust such paths to Android Studio even with C++ support disabled.

Comment: posting the ```build.gradle``` would help in fixing the issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the helpful comments. I may not get a chance to looks at this today, but I will get back to you on this, because it's something I'd like to look at in the future.

Comment: @Michael Turns out that was the case.

Comment: @AlexCohn That wasn't my problem, but thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing the `externalNativeBuild` blocks within the `build.gradle` app file should do the trick. Also look for any `System.loadLibrary("native-lib");` calls within your java code and remove their relative `static` block.

A more intensive cleanup would be to additionally delete the `CMakeLists.txt` and any C/C++ code from the project.

Comment: This did the trick. I had already caught the `externalNativeBuild` blocks (both of them, I think), so apparently I was missing the `static` blocks you mentioned, in this case the one appearing in `MainActivity.java`.


Now I'd like to know why it can't compile a simple program, but that will be another question for another time. Thank you!