# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android Flutter

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

flutter run fails with gradle. Posting answer as this helped
Issue related to gradle build.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944898/192373

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Answer from:](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-426259512)

This is a problem with an old version of the Android Gradle plugin that only surfaced recently due to mips support being removed from the Android SDK. As stated above, it has nothing to do with the filament project.

**Solution**

Without downloading, updating, or copying anything, you can "fix" the error by simply creating an empty directory where the old version expects it.

**Linux**

```
mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```

**MacOS**

```
mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
```

**Windows**

```
mkdir %ANDROID_HOME%\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android\prebuilt\windows-x86_64
```

The `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable points to the root of the Android SDK installation.

Comment: Not sure why you got so downvoted. Googled/SO'd several answers to this question - going around in circles on how to update the Android Gradle plugin, this is janky but at least allows me to move forward. TY.

Comment: Unbelievable. While it certainly doesn't fix the toolchain per say, it surely fixes the error. Works for Ionic as well.