# Problem on setting up the Android Studio NDK

Tags: android-studio

I tried to run my project on Android Studio on MAC and I got the error called `No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android`.

I googled everything and couldn't figure out what's happening with my Android Studio. I do have the latest version of SDK tools and I have installed the NDK tools too.

I hope you understand.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204135/1571605) answer.

Comment: @ItamarKerbel didn't help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944898/192373